# Typescript Mapped Types with other properties

Tags: typescript

I need to have an object that can have any property of one type but it also needs to have specific, predefined properties of another type.

For example:

```js
const foo = {
    $id: 'id',
    bar: 123
}
```

`$id` is predefined and needs to be a string. `bar` is not predefined, and needs to be a number.

The type definition, in concept, would look like this:

```js
type Foo = {
    $id: string;
    [key: string]: number;
}
```

This type does not work. Is there any way to construct the desired type? I have tried

```js
type Foo = {
    [key: string]: number;
} & { $id: string };
```

but that does not work either.

Comment: There is unfortunately no such type. Please see the answer to the linked question for workarounds.  Note that you have no *mapped type* in this question; perhaps you meant *index signature* instead.